# Can't receive proper format of String from JSON

Tags: java, html, json, string, jsp

I'm trying to read my .json file in .jsp file. The text I want to read is (from polish): "wewnętrzny". Instead of it I receive something like: "wewn�?trzny".

The code I'm using seems to not be working:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(FILE_PATH)); 
        JSONArray tab = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("tab");

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) tab.get(i);
            
            byte[] raw =  jsonObjectRow.get("a").toString().getBytes(ISO_8859_1);
            String a = new String(raw, UTF_8);
            out.println(a);
        }     
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've tried several encodings and all the solutions from: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8. Unfortunatelly, nothing made it work properly.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The file on the server needs to be utf8 so save it as utf8, then no need to convert. Also the meta tag in the html page needs to be utf8

Comment: Actually I have my .json file locally. I see wrong characters in debugger, so the meta tag shouldn't be the case. Anyway, ow to set the encoding of .json file?

Comment: Use for example notepad++ to save as UTF8

Comment: The file is encoded in UTF-8. What else can you suggest?

Comment: change to iso-8859-2, assuming file is encoded this way, iso-8859-1 is for no PL

Comment: In Java I only have option: ISO-8859-1. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out!

In code it should be only:

```
 String a = jsonObjectRow.get("a").toString();
```

And the file should be saved in **windows-1250** encoding!

Thank's @marcinj for your advice!